# MVC 4 difference between User.Identity.Name vs WebSecurity.CurrentUserName

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC 4, what's the difference between  `User.Identity.Name` and `WebSecurity.CurrentUserName`? Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Courtesy of Reflector:

```
public static class WebSecurity
{
    ...

    public static string CurrentUserName
    {
        get
        {
            return Context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

So let's answer your questions:

> what's the difference between `User.Identity.Name` and `WebSecurity.CurrentUserName`?

None.

> Can I use them interchangeably?

Yes.